# Continue TestNG test after failed method

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have a TestNG suite set up to perform a number of selenium tests that.  The suite has a number of tests in it, which each have a number of classes, which each have one or two test methods.  I am currently experiencing behavior where the whole test ( tag) will stop if one test method fails (i.e. results will look like: pass, pass, pass, fail, skip, skip, skip, skip, skip, skip).

Is there a way for me to set up my tests so that a single method failure won't prevent the others from running?  My test methods are mostly independent from one another, and the classes definitely are, but all of the classes are sharing a WebDriver instance.

Here is an example of one of my  tags in my XML file.  There are several other test cases with the same class list but different parameters.  unfortunately I cannot show my actual code as it contains privileged information.

```
<test name="OS_X_Mavericks_Firefox_27_Test">
    <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
    <parameter name="browser_version" value="27.0" />
    <parameter name="os" value="OS X" />
    <parameter name="os_version" value="Mavericks" />
    <parameter name="resolution" value="1920x1080" />
    <classes>
        <class name="SuperTestClass" />
        <class name="testClass1" />
        <class name="testClass2" />
        <class name="testClass3" />
        <class name="testClass4" />
        <class name="testClass5" />
        <class name="testClasa6" />
        <class name="testClass7" />
        <class name="testClass8" />
        <class name="testClass9" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: We need to see your code, or this is just a guessing game. See [Ask]!

Comment: I added as much code as I could.  I can provide more information if needed

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was with my inheritance structure.  I had an @AfterClass method in SuperTestClass, which all of the other test classes inherited from.  So, when one test failed in the @AfterClass method, all subsequent tests that inherited from SuperTestClass (all of the tests) failed.